# AngularJS Foundation directive sticky topbar not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to make the AngularJS Foundation topbar directive sticky. See documentation: http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/#topbar

Normally, this should work by adding the standard `sticky-class', nl. 'sticky'. However, this doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
<top-bar class="sticky">
<ul class="title-area">
  <li class="name">
    <h1><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>
  </li>
  <li toggle-top-bar class="menu-icon"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
</ul>

<top-bar-section>
  <!-- Right Nav Section -->
  <ul class="right">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
    <li has-dropdown>
      <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
      <ul top-bar-dropdown>
        <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Left Nav Section -->
  <ul class="left">
    <li><a href="#">Left</a></li>
  </ul>
</top-bar-section>
</top-bar>
```

In the [source code](http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/mm-foundation-tpls-0.4.0.js), I find the following:

```
$scope.settings.stickyClass = $scope.stickyClass || 'sticky';
$scope.settings.stickyOn = $scope.stickyOn || 'all';
[...]
var isSticky = $scope.isSticky = function () {
       var sticky = topbarContainer.hasClass($scope.settings.stickyClass);
       if (sticky && $scope.settings.stickyOn === 'all') {
            return true;
       } 
       else if (sticky && mediaQueries.small() && $scope.settings.stickyOn === 'small') {
            return true;
       } 
       else if (sticky && mediaQueries.medium() && $scope.settings.stickyOn === 'medium') {
            return true;
       } 
       else if (sticky && mediaQueries.large() && $scope.settings.stickyOn === 'large') {
            return true;
       }
       return false;
       };
```

`$scope.settings.stickyClass = $scope.stickyClass || 'sticky'` and `$scope.settings.stickyOn = $scope.stickyOn || 'all'`, so simply adding the default sticky class (`sticky`) should be enough. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you put some sample code and maybe elaborate your question?

Comment: @stevemao I've basically just used the sample code in the documentation and added the sticky class. See edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was:

```
var topbarContainer = topbar.parent();
```

In other words, the `sticky`class needs to be applied to the `<div>`before the top-bar directive. I've tried it and it works this way.